# Редактирование аудиофайлов Android

Tags: android, аудио, java

### Подскажите, пожалуйста, решение для двух задач:

1. Создать из нескольких n-секундных
      файлов один n-секундный (наложение)
2. Создать из нескольких аудиофайлов 
      один путем конкатенации (поочередно) 
      с паузами одинаковой длительности 
      между ними.

Все это на Java под Android.

Comment: декодируете в pcm, подгоняете частоту и другие параметры, потом просто склеиваете два массива и записываете в новый файл, при необходимости преобразовав в нужный формат.

Comment: это да, решение второй задачи, с первой как это сделать я слабо себе представляю. а такие классы как javax.sound.sampled.* из Android 2.1+ убрали